# Tensorflow Dataset.bucket_by_sequence_length throws TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to construct a dataset of variable length English/Japanese sentences for a machine translation problem, but I can't get the `Dataset.bucket_by_sequence_length` function to work. It throws the following:

```
TypeError: Tensor.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'op', 
'value_index', and 'dtype'
```

Despite my best efforts I have not been able to diagnose the problem. I've tried using a named function for `element_length_func`, passing a single dataset entry, passing only the english sentences, and trying various manual and dynamically generated values for `bucket_boundaries` and `bucket_batch_sizes`. The code for constructing the dataset from a list of lists of varying length containing integer indexes is included below. Any suggestions or possible solutions?

```
# Create initial dataset
eng, jap = map(list, zip(*data))
assert len(eng) == len(jap)
eng = tf.ragged.constant(eng, dtype=tf.uint16)
jap = tf.ragged.constant(jap, dtype=tf.uint16)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((eng, jap))

# Bucket based on sequence length
vocab = tokenizer.get_vocab()
dataset = dataset.bucket_by_sequence_length(
    element_length_func=lambda x, _=None: tf.shape(x)[0],
    bucket_boundaries=[100],
    bucket_batch_sizes=[BATCH_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE],
    padding_values=vocab["[PAD]"],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like `bucket_by_sequence_length()` (or more precisely, `PaddedBatchDataset`) supports ragged tensor inputs.

(You can check that in your case, `dataset.element_spec` consists of `tf.RaggedTensorSpec`, while `PaddedBatchDataset` wants `tf.TensorSpec`: [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.9.1/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L5166))

Is it meaningful to pair input data like this instead:

```
eng, jap = # some iterables (and *not* tensors)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((                                                 
    tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda:eng, tf.uint16, output_shapes=[None]),   
    tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda:jap, tf.uint16, output_shapes=[None])))
```

and then to apply `tf.data.experimental.bucket_by_sequence_length()` on the result?